# php dom load form and create element inside

Tags: php, html, domdocument

What im trying to do is load a form and create elements inside it but i end up with something like this:

```
<form id="form_54" accept-charset="utf-8"></form><input type="text" name="name">
```

The outpot i'm lookin for is:

```
<form id="form_54" accept-charset="utf-8"><input type="text" name="name"></form>
```

this is my function:

```
public function input($name, $attributes = array(), $type = 'text')
{
    $form = new DOMDocument();
    $form->loadXML($this->doc->saveHTML());

    $input = $form->createElement('input');
    $input->setAttribute('type', $type);
    $input->setAttribute('name', $name);

    if(isset($attributes))
    {
        foreach($attributes as $attr => $val)
        {
            $input->setAttribute($attr, $val);
        }
    }

    $form->appendChild($input);
    $this->doc->loadXML($form->saveHTML());
}
```

Correct function thanks to Ghost:

```
public function input($name, $attributes = array(), $type = 'text')
{
    $form = $this->doc->getElementsByTagName('form')->item(0);

    $input = $this->doc->createElement('input');
    $input->setAttribute('type', $type);
    $input->setAttribute('name', $name);

    if(isset($attributes))
    {
        foreach($attributes as $attr => $val)
        {
            $input->setAttribute($attr, $val);
        }
    }

    $form->appendChild($input);
    $this->doc->appendChild($form);
}
```

Comment: so whats the problem?

Comment: Where are you adding `form`? Is it already in `DOM`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you're appending on the parent element instead of the form. Try to target the form first, then making the append.

```
public function input($name, $attributes = array(), $type = 'text')
{
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadXML($this->doc->saveHTML());
    // target the form
    $form = $dom->getElementsByTagName('form')->item(0);

    $input = $dom->createElement('input');
    $input->setAttribute('type', $type);
    $input->setAttribute('name', $name);

    if(isset($attributes))
    {
        foreach($attributes as $attr => $val)
        {
            $input->setAttribute($attr, $val);
        }
    }

    $form->appendChild($input);
    $this->doc->loadXML($form->saveHTML());
}
```

Comment: your solution didn't work. however the getElementsByTagName('form')->item(0); that you mentioned was what i needed. so i ended up with the correct function with i added to my question. Thank You!

Comment: @jailbird.phoenix oh yeah, i forgot the instance of of your object was inside `->doc`, anyway glad this helped